# i'm trying to get an integer return from a def equation

Tags: python

I'm trying to get it so my code will return  just the integer of 2 in stead of 2.5464893461251985

```
def number_of_cookies(amount, height, radius):
    return(amount/10)/(radius*radius*3.14158*height)

print (number_of_cookies(40, 0.5, 1))
assert number_of_cookies(40, 0.5, 1) == 2
assert number_of_cookies(400, 0.5, 1) == 25
assert number_of_cookies(1200, 0.3, 1) == 127
```

Comment: Are you looking for [math.floor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=floor#math.floor) ?

Comment: Any of `round()`, `floor division`, or casting to `int()` could work, depending on your ultimate purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def number_of_cookies(amount, height, radius):
    return int((amount/10)/(radius*radius*3.14158*height))
```

Setting to `int` will avoid the `float` precision you are seeing

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. If you want it to become an integer, you can use `int`:

```
def number_of_cookies(amount, height, radius):
    return int((amount / 10) / (radius * radius * 3.14158 * height))
```

If there is a specified number of decimal places you want to round it to, you can use `round`:

```
def number_of_cookies(amount, height, radius):
    return round((amount / 10) / (radius * radius * 3.14158 * height), 0)
```

Finally, if you want to round it down, you can do this:

```
import math
def number_of_cookies(amount, height, radius):
    return math.floor((amount / 10) / (radius * radius * 3.14158 * height))
```